# javascript regular expression whitespace class not matched but space is matched

Tags: javascript, regex

This gives me an error

```
let templateUrlReg = new RegExp("templateUrl:\s+(.+)");
let templateUrlRes = templateUrlReg.exec("templateUrl: 'components/search/search.html'");
console.log(templateUrlRes[0]);
console.log(templateUrlRes[1]);
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

When i change the first line to:

```
let templateUrlReg = new RegExp("templateUrl: (.+)");
```

I get the expression.

What is wrong here?
Shouldn't be \s a superset of a normal space?

Comment: Use `var templateUrlReg = /templateUrl:\s+(.+)/;`

Comment: I think it's doing a character escape of `\s`.  You might try making it `\\s`.

Comment: thanks anubhava.  and amy. both worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double backslash when using double quotes, try:

```
let templateUrlReg = new RegExp("templateUrl:\\s+(.+)");
```

Explained in the last paragraph of the [MDN description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description)